# Facebook Share Button shares Google.com instead of current page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I'm using the Facebook share button on my blog. I've basically just made it as a link with counter (using [Sharrre](http://sharrre.com/) jQuery plugin). (Problem is not with the plugin, have already tested that).

When you click the link to share, then the popup window has a box to share Google.com. When I go to the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), it tells me that the canonical URL for this [blog page](http://fieldedge.com.au/2015/10/08/6-ways-to-raise-funding-for-your-cause-online/#blog-share) is Google.com. I've looked at the page source, and that is definitely not the canonical URL.

So, what I've done to try and force it to use the correct links, is to include the OG meta tags: og:url og:title and og:type which is definitely getting outputted to the document. But Facebook still shares Google.com when I click the share link, and the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)'s output stays the same when I ask it to scrape the URL again.

The blog page where this is happening is: http://fieldedge.com.au/2015/10/08/6-ways-to-raise-funding-for-your-cause-online/#blog-share

Any ideas how to fix this? Half expecting the answer to be "Facebook is just crap" as per the usual scenario, because I've scoured the web and cannot find a similar issue anywhere.

Comment: After take a quick look at the demos and without your current code, i think it might be data-url attribute in your code is set to google.com

Comment: Nope, this is what I've got: data-url="<?php the_permalink() ?>"

Comment: It's seems like I can't event access your given url,  http://fieldedge.com.au redirect me to google.com

Comment: Ah, excellent, thank you. I've noticed that a WordPress plugin was blocking all countries outside of Australia, which would explain why Facebook couldn't scrape it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't a Facebook issue. It was an issue with a setting in WordFence security plugin for WordPress. It had accidentally been set to block client facing pages from being viewed by countries outside of Australia. While this problem is unlikely to occur with anyone else much, it may.